# How to build webrtc with ios objective c

Tags: objective-c, webrtc

I' m trying to build AppRTCDemom example from google webrtc source code, I'm following the readme file, but after trying this  "gclient runhooks" I get:

"key_id gyp variable needs to be set explicitly because there are multiple codesigning keys, or none"

Can someone say what happend? what is missing here?

tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is if you have more than one iOS developer key.  In the libjingle_examples.gyp file line 271 there is this note above the offending line.

```
 # Total HACK to give a more informative message when multiple
 # codesigning keys are present in the default keychain.  Ideally
 # we could pick more intelligently among the keys, but as a
 # first cut just tell the developer to specify a key identity
 # explicitly.

'key_id%': (security find-identity -p codesigning -v | grep "iPhone Developer" | awk \'{print $2}\')
```

When you run the command directly:

```
security find-identity -p codesigning -v | grep "iPhone Developer" | awk '{print $2}'
555XXXX6DA325E6097E5301381XXXXXXD35D620E
315XXXX6B19AD10A0F4567XXXX03B1BXXXXXXXXX
```

it list two dev ids, which is the issue, so I edited libjingle_examples.gyp line 271 and added `| head -1` to have it only return 1 key, in this case the top or first key.  I also double checked in Xcode to ensure that the top key is my current one.

I have been working in this space for the past few months now and webrtc on iOS is not easy. To help this problem I have added a github repo with a working example of an iOS app using webrtc.

https://github.com/gandg/webrtc-ios

The site references the google code site as well, so it should be a helpful starting point.

Answer (score 5):

Gp-coder's solution was only half the fix for me. After making the change he recommended, I ran into another similar error in another file:

> AssertionError: Multiple codesigning identities for identity: iPhone
>   Developer

This assertion is occurring in the following file:

webrtc/trunk/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py

Strangely, the line after the assertion will take the first code signing identity in the list so the solution was as easy as commenting out the assertion on line 793.  That assumes you actually want the first code signing identity. If not, change the index being used on the results array on line 796 to whatever you need.

I ended up [writing a blog post](http://ninjanetic.com/how-to-get-started-with-webrtc-and-ios-without-wasting-10-hours-of-your-life/) with these changes as well as a few others you need to get the full build working.

Comment: In file trunk/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py and at lines 832-833 comment the following line :
#assert identity not in cache or fingerprint == cache[identity], (
#”Multiple codesigning fingerprints for identity: %s” % identity)  will solve your problem,jzn. Reference from http://ninjanetic.com/how-to-get-started-with-webrtc-and-ios-without-wasting-10-hours-of-your-life/